# FormCollection inputs on action method have null values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get values of form inputs on action method.

**MVC View**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Report", "Home"))
                   {
                        <div class="common_input Volunteer_input">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label for="firstName">Reporter:</label>

                                    <div class="select_option_one">
                                        <input type="text" id="ReporterCountries" class="ct-select2 ReporterCountriesList" />

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label for="firstName">Partner:</label>
                                    <div class="select_option_one">
                                        <input type="text" name="PartnersCountries" id="PartnersCountries"  class="ct-select2 CountryList" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                            <h3>Comparators</h3>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label for="firstName">Partner:</label>
                                    <div class="select_option_one">
                                        <input type="text" name="CompareCountryList" id="CompareCountryList" class="ct-select2 CountryList" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label for="firstName">Rank Growth:</label>
                                    <div class="select_option_one">
                                        <input type="text" name="RankGrowth" id="RankGrowth" class="ct-select2 RankGrowth" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="sub_submit">
                                        <button type="submit" class="common_btn hvr-sweep-to-bottom">View<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                   }
```

**Action Method for Home Controller**

```
public ActionResult Report(FormCollection form)
        {
            ViewData["ReporterCountries"] = Request.Form["ReporterCountries"];;
            return RedirectToAction("Index","data");
        }
```

When I try to retrieve the values of input on action controller I am receving all the control on the view but values are coming as null.

Comment: Because you do not have a form control with `name="ReporterCountries"`. Forms post back the name/value pairs of their successful controls (not their `id` attributes). Then you need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics of MVC. You pass a model to your view, you bind to the model using the `HtmlHelper` methods and you pass back that model to the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for spotting it, I did missed to add name="ReporterCountries" which I did added to other controls.